# Is this truly a story-id question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, story-identification

There's [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/173954/loki-impersonating-hydra-red-skull-or-nazis) which is definitely a valid question. However, it's tagged with [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification). Is this a valid tag and why? I honestly don't think it matches, but there doesn't seem to be another matching tag (e.g. [scene-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scene-identification)).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [story-id](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-id) tag is for the generic identification of **any science fiction or fantasy property.** It doesn't strictly have to be a (written) story. It could also be a game, song, film, book, movie ***or whatever*** as long as it fits within the site's scope.

> Use for identifying **a work** of SF or Fantasy, including novels, movies, comic books, fanfic, TV series, video games, etc. Use with other tags to specify the type of media, eg. [short-stories]. Use [episode-identification] for identifying a single episode of a known series, whether TV, book, or comic. Use [actor-identification], [character-identification], [music-identification], or [object-identification] for those specific ID requests.

It would help if OP qualified it with one of the media tags, but in this case, they *don't actually know whether it's a TV show or a film* so any attempt to additionally qualify it would be pointless.

Comment: Couldn’t it be [tag:episode-identification] because it’s part of the greater Marvel thing?

Comment: @Stormblessed - Theoretically. Except that OP has no idea whether it's from a TV series, a film, a comedy skit or anything else.